# How do I add PHP-LDAP to a Docker Container

Tags: linux, php, docker, ldap, mediawiki

I installed a MediaWiki on a Docker in CentOS 8. I want to integrate LDAP. I installed the LDAP extensions and activated it in the LocalSettings.php file. Now, when I try to login in my wiki I get this error:

```
[c04f74d86c621c5c996ce413] /index.php/Spezial:PluggableAuthLogin Error from line 244 of /var/www/html/extensions/LDAPProvider/src/PlatformFunctionWrapper.php: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

I searched for a solution the last 5 daysand I'm finding nothing that helps me. I read that I have to install PHP-LDAP in the Docker container, but how can I do that?

Comment: You should activate LDAP PHP extension in PHP configuration.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm sorry, I'm new to Linux and the other stuff.

Comment: If it were a real machine, it would be `sudo yum install php7.4-ldap && sudo phpenmod ldap && sudo service php7.4-fpm restart` assuming you use PHP 7.4 an php-fpm. But for Docker, I can't advise you.

Answer (score 4):

[MediaWiki does not provide any PHP extensions](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki). You have to write your own docker file and use the below helpers to install **ldap** extension and build the image from it :

```
FROM mediawiki:<version>
RUN \ 
apt-get update && \
apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
docker-php-ext-install ldap
```

Comment: Thank you for the lines but I do get an error: ```#20 0.284 E: Unable to locate package libldap2-dev```. I am using ```FROM php:7.2-apache```

Comment: Hm yes, I have problems too, using `FROM php:7.4-fpm` and `RUN apt-get install -y libldap2-dev` getting `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libldap2-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100`